# Adding icon to an image

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an `<Image>` inside a `<Border>` inside a `<Grid>`. I have a baseMap.png loaded into that image (Source). Using the scroll-wheel I can rotate the image using a Matrix.

I would now like to add an icon (say, push_pin.png) at an arbitrary x,y on the Image, in effect building a new Image by merging baseMap.png and push_pin.png with the later offset by some x & y relative to baseMap.png.

How does one do that best?

Dave

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Canvas` to position the icon, while displaying the `baseMap.png` image in an [`ImageBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) set as the `Canvas.Background` like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Border>
        <Canvas>
            <Canvas.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/YourAppName;component/Images/baseMap.png" />
            </Canvas.Background>
            <Image Source="/YourAppName;component/Images/push_pin.png"
                Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100" />  <!-- Positioning -->
        </Canvas>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

You can either hard code the positions of the icon, or better still, data bind to them instead. The `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties can also be used in animations and the `ImageBrush` class has various properties to affect how it displays the image.

Comment: I need to be able to pan/zoom/rotate the baseMap...  as well as the icon with it... can an ImageBrush be pan/zoom/rotated? What if I need to add several icons and lines?

Comment: The `ImageBrush` is like a copy of your original element. If you rotate your original image, the `ImageBrush` will be rotated too. If you pass a `Visual` containing several shapes to an `ImageBrush`, then the `ImageBrush` will display the several shapes too. Read the linked page for more information.

Comment: I am still missing something here. Let's say I have a map of the US as the background as you suggest. Then I place a pushpin graphic on New York city using a canvas. That seems fine. Now I use a matrix to rotate the background counter-clockwise 45 degrees. How does the pushpin follow New York?

Comment: You don't rotate the `Background`... you rotate the *whole* `Canvas`, icon and all.